# UrlEncode safe values or not

Tags: c#, asp.net

Should I UrlEncode query string values that are always safe? For example, an md5 hash in the following query string.

`?value=3e25960a79dbc69b674cd4ec67a72c62`

Comment: I would. It won't hurt anything and if you ever change what type of value is passed, it could avoid a bug.

Comment: Encoding for securing URL, md5 will be hacked.